# How to implement Java's Comparable module in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, priority-queue

I'm currently going over [Robert Sedgewick's Algorithms](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/) book. In the book for the implementation of a Priority Queue there is the use of the Comparable module. While going over the [top k frequent elements leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/) I noticed that there would be an error in my Ruby implementation.

```
def top_k_frequent(nums, k)
  ans = []
  h = Hash.new(0)

  nums.each do |num|
    h[num] += 1
  end

  heap = Heap.new
  h.each do |k,v|
    heap.insert({k => v})
  end

  k.times do
    a = heap.del_max
    ans.push(a.keys[0])
  end

  ans
end


class Heap
  def initialize
    @n = 0
    @pq = []
  end

  def insert(v)
    @pq[@n += 1] = v
    swim(@n)
  end

  def swim(k)
    while k > 1 && less((k / 2).floor, k)
      swap((k / 2).floor, k)
      k = k/2
    end
  end

  def swap(i, j)
    temp = @pq[i]
    @pq[i] = @pq[j]
    @pq[j] = temp
  end

  def less(i, j)
    @pq[i].values[0] < @pq[j].values[0]
  end

  def del_max
    max = @pq[1]
    swap(1, @n)
    @n -= 1
    @pq[@n + 1] = nil
    sink(1)
    max
  end

  def sink(k)
    while 2 * k <= @n
      j = 2 * k

      if !@pq[j + 1].nil?
        j += 1 if j > 1 && @pq[j].values[0] < @pq[j + 1].values[0]
      end
      break if !less(k, j)

      swap(k, j)
      k = j
    end
  end
end
```

Above is the Java Priority Queue implementation.

Comment: Ruby has a Comparable module in fact: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Comparable.html

Comment: I don't quite understand what your problem is ("the comparisons would fail" is not a very precise error description), but it seems the root cause is that `Hash`es are not `Comparable` in Ruby. However, `Map`s are also not `Comparable` in Java, so I find it hard to understand why you want to implement Java's `Comparable` in Ruby, when the problem is exactly the same in Java?

Comment: typo `initilize`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Your right, basically I'm thinking how to compare two objects or hashes without a drastic change to the API.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's comparable operator is `<=>` which will return one of `-1`, `0`, `1` and `nil` (`nil` mean could not compare).

In order to compare two objects , both need to implement a method `def <=>(other)`. This is not on `Object`, so is not available on any objects that don't implement it or extend from a class that does implement it. Numbers and Strings, for example, do have an implementation. Hashes do not.

I *think* in your case, the issue is slightly different.

When you call `queue.insert(my_hash)` what you're expecting is for the algorithm to break up `my_hash` and build from that. Instead, the algorithm takes the hash as a single, atomic object and inserts that.

If you add something like:

```
class Tuple
  attr_accessor :key, :value

  def initialize(key, value)
    @key = key
    @value = value
  end

  def <=>(other)
    return nil unless other.is_a?(Tuple)
    value <=> other.value
  end
end
```

then this will allow you to do something like:

```
hsh = { 1 => 3, 2 => 2, 3 => 1}
tuples = hsh.map { |k, v| Tuple.new(k, v) }

tuples.each { |tuple| my_heap.insert(tuple) }
```

you will have all of your data in the heap.

When you retrieve an item, it will be a tuple, so you can just call `item.key` and `item.value` to access the data.